# Most efficient way store lat and lng for searches with distance with MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, geolocation

I am just researching the best way to use MYSQL to store lat and lng coordinates so that I can search for matching fields within a certain distance. I have done a lot of research and coming up with all different answers but my issue is that they all seem to be a few years out of date.

I think the best way would be using MyISAM tables with Spatial indexes?

I have tried this to insert in database

```
INSERT INTO `op_live`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(52.414661 -1.557670)'));
```

and this to search

```
SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(52.454178)) * cos(radians(x(`op_live`.`locations`.`coordinates`))) * cos(radians(y(`op_live`.`locations`.`coordinates`)) - radians(-1.557670)) + sin(radians(52.454178)) * sin(radians(x(`op_live`.`locations`.`coordinates`))))) AS distance 
FROM `op_live`.`locations`
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY id
;
```

Now this works but I will need to update the lat and lng very regular and I cannot seem to do it with getting errors. So what I am looking for is ideas on the best way to setup the database in the first place and ways to search it within a certain distance. It will not be but lets say for instance there will be 100,000 records. I will need it to be as fast as possible. Also I will be using node to perform all the tasks.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You need to fir calculate a bounding box for the circle with radius `distance`, and use `MBRContains` or `MBRWithin` to filter out most of the unnecessary rows (more info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html)). Then you use your formula to "fine tune" the result.

Comment: Ok thanks but I don't understand what your referring to? MBRContains? Do you have any links or code or anything for me to look at? Thanks

Comment: There is a link to the docs right there in the comment

Comment: Yes sorry just looking at this. Seems like a slow way of doing this by making a polygon etc? Maybe reading it wrong but there seems other more easy quicker ways?